# Where is a non-aggregate value that was not included in a group?

Tags: sql, teradata

I get this error message, but I cannot see where exactly is the problem:

*Error Code - 3504 Error Message - [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 16.20.00.12] [Error 3504] [SQLState HY000] Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group.*

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM trnsact.saledate)||EXTRACT(YEAR FROM trnsact.saledate) AS MonthYear, 
       SUM(trnsact.amt)/COUNT(DISTINCT trnsact.saledate) AS AvgSales
FROM (SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM saledate)||EXTRACT(YEAR FROM saledate) AS MonthYear, store
      FROM trnsact
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SALEDATE)>19
      GROUP BY MonthYear, store) AS cleaned 
JOIN trnsact ON cleaned.MonthYear=MonthYear AND cleaned.store=trnsact.store 
WHERE STYPE='P' AND saledate < '2005-08-01' 
GROUP BY MonthYear
ORDER BY AvgSales;
```

Comment: Doubly defined MonthYear?

Comment: SQL doesn't allow using alias names from the same query in the `HAVING` clause, because the `HAVING` clause gets executed before the `SELECT` clause, so the alias defined in the `SELECT` clause is not known to the `HAVING` clause..

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: Standard SQL doesn't allow it, but Teradata SQL :-)

Comment: I'd avoid reusing MonthYear anyway. Too confusing as it is now.

Comment: Snowflake allows that too

Comment: Dnoeth's answer is good.  Just as an alternative, in case you really want to combine month and year, use `to_char(<date col>,'MMYYYY')`.  Concatenating numbers together results in implicit casts to char, just don't do it.

Answer (score 2):

Teradata allows reusing an alias in any place, but the are some scoping rules and the parser is probably confused because there're two `monthyear` columns, an alias of the outer Select and a column name form the inner Select. Using two different names should fix that. Additionally it will be more efficient to use separate columns for year/month, e.g.:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM trnsact.saledate) as mon,
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM trnsact.saledate) AS yr, 
  SUM(trnsact.amt)/COUNT(DISTINCT trnsact.saledate) AS AvgSales

FROM  
 (
   SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM saledate) as mon2,
      EXTRACT(YEAR FROM saledate) AS yr2, store
   FROM trnsact
   -- fixed the order, Teradata allows that wrong order, but it's really confusing
   GROUP BY mon2, yr2, store
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SALEDATE)>19
 ) AS cleaned 
 
JOIN trnsact 
ON cleaned.mon2=mon
AND cleaned.yr2=yr 
AND cleaned.store=trnsact.store 

WHERE STYPE='P'  
  AND saledate < DATE '2005-08-01' -- using a date literal is safe

GROUP BY yr,mon

ORDER BY AvgSales;
```

Edit:

This can probably be simplified to:

```
SELECT
   EXTRACT(YEAR FROM saledate) AS yr
  ,EXTRACT(MONTH FROM saledate) AS mon
   -- = SUM(trnsact.amt)/COUNT(DISTINCT trnsact.saledate)
  ,SUM(sumamt)/COUNT(DISTINCT saledate) AS AvgSales
FROM
 (
   SELECT saledate, store, SUM(amt) AS sumamt
   FROM sales_fact
   WHERE STYPE='P'  
     AND saledate < DATE '2005-08-01' -- using a date literal is safe
   GROUP BY 1, 2
   -- = HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SALEDATE) > 19
   QUALIFY COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY store_id) > 19
 ) AS cleaned
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY AvgSales;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers! I am very happy to learn something new. And the fixed query does work!

But the simplified version with QUALIFY COUNT function gives me different results. The data clean-up rule I am supposed to use is: “only include this data
in my calculation if the date-month label of this group of data in my store is present in the list of date-month labels that have at least 20 days of data in this store.” Which makes me add year and month to the subquery, which again leads to the reuse of month and year :(

Comment: I forgot to add year/month to the QUALIFY, no need to add it to the select list: `QUALIFY COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY store_id, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM saledate) ,EXTRACT(MONTH FROM saledate)) > 19` should work

Comment: Thank you! This qualify count function seems to be a very neat trick!